# Having issues adjusting desktop display trying to keep the integrity of the mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an embedded video that I used CSS to have responsive with mobile. In result, I'm unable to center the video on desktop display without adjusting the CSS that is currently making the video responsive. What is the best way to center the video while keeping the video responsive for mobile.

I've tried messing around with CSS only to break what I have.

```
<style>
body,h1 {font-family: "Raleway", Arial, sans-serif}
h1,h2,h5 {letter-spacing: 6px}
.w3-row-padding img {margin-bottom: 12px}
.responsive-image {
  height: auto;
  width: 55%;
}

.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 45.25%;
padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
max-width: 853px;
height: 100%;
max-height: 480px;
}

</style>
```

```
<div class="w3-center video-container">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dy85sXnsJDs" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I'm using a w3 school template, so the w3-center is what centers all of my stuff.

[image: video]

Comment: Have you tried using media queries? You can set different css rules for mobile and desktop sizes: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking 2 questions.

The first is "how do you maintain a video's aspect ratio?"

```
<section class="section-name">

  <aside class="video">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dy85sXnsJDs"
      frameborder="0" width="560" height="315">  
    </iframe>
  </aside>

</section>
```

and then "how do I center an element"

```
/* setup part a - the video aspect ratio */
.video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 52%; /* arbitrary for now */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.video iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* part b - the 'centering an element' */
.section-name {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.section-name .video {
  width: 600px;
}
```

BUT - this is brittle... and I suggest you use http://fitvidsjs.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` to the iframe.